# How can an element find its own index in a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, tree

I'm trying to reimplement a tree data structure using `std::unique_ptr`, and the idea is that the parent node would own its children, who are stored in a vector of `unique_ptr`.

For interface reasons, I need a method where the node destroys itself. In this case, I think the node to erase itself from the children vector in its parent.

The following implementation 'works' (in a c++11 compiler), but it is ugly as hell and I'm sure it is a sub optimum way of dealing with this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Node {
    typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> vec_node_uptr;

    unsigned        id;
    Node*           parent;
    vec_node_uptr   child_nodes;

    // ctor
    Node(unsigned id): id(id){ parent = nullptr; }

    void add_child(Node* new_child){
        new_child -> parent = this;
        child_nodes.push_back( std::unique_ptr<Node>(std::move(new_child) ) );
    }

    int where_am_i(){
        int result_ = 0;
        for(auto& i: this -> parent -> child_nodes) {
            if (this == i.get()) {
                return result_;
            } else {
                result_++;
            }
        }
    }

    void suicide(){
        parent -> child_nodes.erase(parent -> child_nodes.begin()+ where_am_i());
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> root(new Node(0));

    root -> add_child(new Node(1));
    root -> add_child(new Node(2));

    root -> child_nodes[0] -> add_child(new Node(3));
    root -> child_nodes[0] -> add_child(new Node(4));
    root -> child_nodes[1] -> add_child(new Node(5));
    root -> child_nodes[1] -> add_child(new Node(6));

    root -> child_nodes[1] -> suicide();

    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? Maybe using `std::find`?

Comment: I think this question would be better suited for [codereview.se]

Comment: I would move the responsibility to the parent. The child would call parent->remove_child(this)

Comment: @Enigma: OK, but the fundamental problem of finding the child remains unchanged. All that changes is the location of the source code that does it :-P

Comment: In this case, the parent is not the sole owner of its children, because the children can determine when their own lifetime ends.  I suspect that is why your solution seems hamfisted, as `unique_ptr` is designed for a situation where that pointer has sole ownership over the object in question.  In effect, your design has the parent with a unique "weak" pointer into the child, whose lifetime is self-managed.  An approach might be to implement `unique_weak_ptr` and `unique_strong_ptr` and a `self_ownership` CRTP class... even then, the pointer-to-child would invalidate, but not the count.

Comment: @Yakk: Is that true? I feel like the parent still owns its children memory, i.e. children are automatically destructed when the parent is deleted... 'suicide' is just a convenience function, that effectively calls a parent method. Please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: Someone else is ordering the parent to destroy a child.  While this might nominally be the parent that is "actually doing the destruction", the order comes from elsewhere, and is not "parent-directed".  If it was parent directed, the parent would know which child it was destroying, and wouldn't be searching for the object it was told to destroy in its internal child storage, would it?  I'd consider this an "and" ownership situation, where if either party doesn't want the object to exist, the object dies, and both are notified.  Hence your complications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this a bit more elegantly using find_if and a lambda:

```
void suicide() 
{
    auto& parentsChildren = parent->child_nodes;
    parentsChildren.erase(find_if(begin(parentsChildren), end(parentsChildren), 
                           [&](const unique_ptr<Node>& node) { return node.get() == this; }));
}
```

Comment: fits the bill. I haven't looked at lambda expr yet. Any comments on performance?

Comment: std::find_if will perform a linear search on parentsChildren, so the complexity isn't constant like as in j_random_hacker's answer (it's about the same as what you were doing before). I could be wrong, but the lambda will probably be inlined, so no performance problems there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a constant-time `where_am_i()` with your current data structures, you will need to store either an index or an iterator in the node itself.  This is (a) duplicative and (b) will entail further complications, because whenever you delete a node that is not the last child of its parent, you will need to update the indices/iterators for all subsequent children...

Then again, it may be that there is no real advantage to making a constant-time `where_am_i()`, because deleting an element from a vector is O(n) anyway unless you will always be deleting from the end (or near the end).

But if you will usually be deleting from the end, and if it is never necessary to transfer ownership of a set of children away from a parent node, then here is an alternative, simpler design that avoids the need to store indices or iterators in each node:

The C++ Standard guarantees that `std::vector`s, like arrays, will have their contents laid out contiguously in memory.  So if the `child_nodes` vector actually stored its elements by value -- i.e. if it were declared as

```
typedef std::vector<Node> vec_node_uptr;
vec_node_uptr child_nodes;
```

then you could find the position in constant time by simply subtracting the address of the first element in the vector from the address of the given element, letting pointer arithmetic do the division for you:

```
size_t where_am_i() {
    return this - &parent->child_nodes[0];
}
```

Comment: Deleting from the end is irrelevant. Transfer to a different parent node is already covered if the tree has parent links at all. (And if it doesn't, the algorithms are already written to avoid that issue.) There's no reason to implement `where_am_i` any other way.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: really interesting idea. I expect to use do way more transfer of ownership between nodes than deleting though.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: As you're not the OP, on what authority do you say that deleting from the end is irrelevant?  Some algorithms can be designed to delete only from the end, while others can't, so the overall time complexity will depend on which of these categories the OP's algorithm is in.  Do you know which algorithms the OP intends to use?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Because it has no bearing on whether the solution works or not. `this - &parent->children[0]` is the solution, period. You said "if … and … then the solution is to subtract" but they're false conditions.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: All I'm saying is that the solution I propose only *gives you some benefit* if you will always be deleting from (near) the end. If you won't be deleting from (near) the end, then my O(1) solution will be of no real use because you'll be performing an O(n) deletion step immediately afterward anyway.  Was that really so unclear?